# SAS PROC PLOT unnecessarily huge chart

Tags: sas

This is code for a HW question in my Multivariate Analysis Class

```
options nodate nonumber;
TITLE 'Problem #1 ';
DATA IRIS;
  INFILE '~\iris.txt';
  INPUT SL SW PW PL Species;
PROC GLM;
  CLASS Species;
  MODEL SL SW PW PL = Species;
  MANOVA H=SPECIES/PRINTE PRINTH;
RUN;
proc candisc data=IRIS out=ftstat;
  CLASS Species;
  VAR SL SW PW PL;
  TITLE 'Discriminant Analysis for Problem #1';
RUN;
goptions reset=all;
PROC PLOT DATA=ftstat uniform;
  PLOT CAN2*CAN1=Species;
RUN;quit;
```

PROC PLOT is currently generating a huge chart, maybe 5-10 pages tall, with ridiculous vertical scaling (something like .05 = an inch+ of computer screen.) It's too big to put in a word document to hand in, and it's not informative as is.

My question is why is my SAS doing this, and can I fix it? I'd love it to be scaled down to a 5" x 5" or something like that...can I do this? (I've a working knowledge of SAS, but I'm far from skilled at it.)

Comment: See [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/63022/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003283225.htm). You can use `goptions` to modify your chart size. And BTW, this question is off topic here.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight I will happily repost elsewhere, if need be. On the topic, however, your solution failed to make my chart smaller :( I do not know what is happening

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ods graphics` and `PROC SGPLOT`.

```
ods graphics on / width=5in height=5in;
PROC SGPLOT DATA=ftstat;
  SCATTER can2*can1=species;
run;
```